# iTextSharp - PdfContentByte causing error on page

Tags: c#, itext

So I'm using PdfContentByte to draw a simple line  in an itextsharp pdf document, but when using it i get an error that says "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly". Does anyone have a solution to this? The error usually pops up after I have selected to print the document.

Here is my code:

```
`cb.BeginText();
                    cb.SetLineWidth(1.0f);
                    cb.MoveTo(37.0f, doc.PageSize.Height - 105.0f);
                    cb.LineTo(doc.PageSize.Width - 37.0f, doc.PageSize.Height - 105.0f);
                    cb.Stroke();
                    cb.EndText();`
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to accept an answer. I came here with the same question and found my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have anything but text operators between a `BeginText()` and `EndText()` pair.  Move your line art code outside them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix on this site:

http://sajeevkumar.com/blog/?p=155

It is more specific to java but I believe the api's are very similar. My other thoughts are to do with there being a page object, sometimes pdf frameworks produce mangled output unless you explicitly create a page object within said pdf and then draw onto the page...